# Why is the set of all integers not a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm new to analysis and I don't understand why under the natural ordering, the set of all integers is not a sequence?

If someone could explain this I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: What is the first integer under the natural ordering?

Comment: It can't be said, right?

Comment: Yes. And that would appear to be a problem in considering the integers as a sequence with the natural order: every sequence has a first element.

Comment: So, using that logic how about - All integers less than or equal to 0?

Comment: Not a sequence under the _natural order_ for the same reason. Of course, you can "turn things around" and get a sequence. Likewise, you can "shuffle" the set all integers to get a sequence.

Comment: I don't understand, wouldn't our first element be zero?

Comment: Not according to the _natural order_ on the non-positive integers. Again, you can "turn this around" to get a sequence.

Comment: @Finance *Integers* usually refers to the set $\mathbb{Z}$, which includes all positive and negative whole numbers, i.e. $0,1,-1,2,-2,\ldots$. *Natural numbers* on the other hand refers to $\mathbb{N}$ which includes only the positive whole numbers, i.e. $0,1,2,\ldots$ (though some people start at $1$ there, not $0$). So maybe you mean "natural numbers" where you say "integers".

Comment: @Finance So with the *natural* order $<$, $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a smallest element, because for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n-1 < n$. The set $\mathbb{N}$, on the other hand, does have a smallest element, namely $0$ (or $1$, again because people disagree on whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: The question doesn't say "sets" it says "all". The question is this - Under the natural ordering which of the following are sequences? a) All integers b) all integers greater than or equal to -100 c) all integers less than or equal to zero.

Comment: So, from what I understood, A is not a sequence because it has no first element, b) this is a sequence right? and c) isn't because the natural ordring would go 0, 1, 2.. not 0, -1, -2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the natural order $<$, the integers are ordered as:

$$\dots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots$$

Whatever element $a_0=n$ you pick to be the first element in the sequence, there exists an integer $n-1$ which is smaller and is not included in your sequence.

As the comments point out, you can use another ordering, starting from 0, to create a sequence which includes every integer, for example

$$0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\dots$$

but this would *not* be the natural order.